# Django login form not keeping input after bad submit

Tags: html, django, django-forms

I have a login form and if a user enters an invalid username or password, the page refreshes and removes the Username value they entered. I would like it so that the username field doesn't empty on failed submit.

**views.py**

```py
def login_page(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('dashboard:dashboard')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('dashboard:dashboard')
        else:
            messages.info(request, 'Username or Password is invalid.')
    return render(request, 'main/login.html', {})
```

**login.html:**

```html
<form id="login-form" action="" method="post" role="form">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6 center" style="border-radius: 16px;">
        <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="5" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Login">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="center">
          <a href="#" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">Forgot Password?</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: The input element is doing as you asked and setting its value to the empty string.

Comment: I am unsure how to parse the input from the user's previous submit into that field.

Comment: Just remove it and browser will keep the cached value. But you should really work with [Django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/) for proper error handling and validation and in your case [django-bootstrap4](https://pypi.org/project/django-bootstrap4/). Also, there's a built-in LoginForm at `django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about passing the username in the context.

try this:

views.py

```
def login_page(request):
    context = {}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('dashboard:dashboard')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('dashboard:dashboard')
        else:
            context["username"] = username
            messages.info(request, 'Username or Password is invalid.')
    return render(request, 'main/login.html', context)
```

login.html:

```
...
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="{{ username }}">
...
```